# Azure Devops Organization Management

Tags: azure-devops

can you please help us with the best practices in terms of managing the organization interms of Azure Devops.
Is it suggested to use two different Azure Devops organization for Development and Production.
How the mobility of resources between organization is supported?
How the resources(pipelines,repos,testplans,boards) can be shared accros organization in Azure Devops?
what is the microsoft recommendations of maintaining the multiple Azure Devops Organizations?

Comment: You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/plan-your-azure-devops-org-structure?view=azure-devops).

Answer (score 0):

There are very few cases to create multiple Azure devops organizations since you can delegate access through project collection administrators to multiple projects. The main reason to create a separate org is for legal or administrative requirements where the two sets of repos/board/pipelines need to be separated and can't have a shared org administrator.
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/blob/master/docs/user-guide/plan-your-azure-devops-org-structure.md